# How to get the value of a "related" selectedIndex in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-select

I have 2 `<select>` lists in my HTML markup. One of them is accessible in the web form and the 2nd is hidden. They both relate to each other.

I want to get the value, not the selectedIndex ID, of `#list2`.

1st list visible in the web form:

```
<select id="list1" name="name" class="form-control">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="004">Alpha</option>
  <option value="001">Beta</option>
  <option value="006">Delta</option>
  <option value="020">Omega</option>
</select>
```

2nd list hidden in the web form:

```
<select id="list2" name="amount" class="form-control" style="display:none">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="004">1.00</option>
  <option value="001">2.00</option>
  <option value="006">3.00</option>
  <option value="020">4.00</option>
</select>
```

**Example:**
When dropdown list item for "Delta" is selected I want to use the value "3.00" in my jQuery function.

Comment: That's going to be a LOT of if statements.

Comment: I've tried Googling and did not come up with something that seemed to be close @j08691

Comment: Ok, so it can't be related in any way @SterlingArcher

Comment: "I've tried googling" doesn't fly here ^ 99% of the time it's a lie because google holds all the answers.

Comment: Someone has to fall into the 1% group - I guess...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/9uprxkmk/1/

```
$('#list1').on('change', function(){
    alert($('#list2 option[value="'+$(this).find(":selected").val()+'"]').html());   
});
```

Comment: this looks exactly like what I was hoping for. Thanks @caramba -- let me try it in my app.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks @caramba. I'll accept that as the answer in 2 mins when SO let's me

Comment: @H.Ferrence you're welcome, glad I could help! Have fun coding

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function(){
    //cache the list
    var $list1 = $('#list1');
    //cache the other list options
    var $list2Options = $('#list2 option');
    
    $list1.on('change', function(){
        //filter on the value and get the second value
        console.log( $list2Options.filter('[value="'+ this.value +'"]').text() );
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="list1" name="name" class="form-control">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="004">Alpha</option>
  <option value="001">Beta</option>
  <option value="006">Delta</option>
  <option value="020">Omega</option>
</select>

<select id="list2" name="amount" class="form-control" style="display:none">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="004">1.00</option>
  <option value="001">2.00</option>
  <option value="006">3.00</option>
  <option value="020">4.00</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Ok, thanks @Taplar. It returns the selectedIndex but not the value of `#list2`

Comment: Fixed.  Accessing text() instead of val()

Comment: Thanks @Taplar. I tried (at)caramba's answer and it worked and it's a bit more concise..

Comment: That cool.  One thing to note between our two answers, mine is caching the dom lookups where his is doing a lookup every time, so there is a difference in work load.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following selector:

```
$("#list1 option:selected").html();
```

That should grab the whatever is in between the opening and closing option tags of the element that is selected.

Comment: or you could use the .text() function